# Moving multiple rects by clicking on one of them

Tags: python, pygame, mouse, move, rect

I've got two lists with 3 rects in each. Can I assign to variables selected1 and selected2 3 rects from each list and move these two rows of rects seperately up and down while keeping the gaps between them? I am beginner and don't know if such constructed code can handle this task.

```
import pygame

# === CONSTANS ===
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
green = (0, 102, 0)
yellow = (255, 204, 0)
grid_color = (224, 224, 224)

width = 1200
height = 720

k = 10

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

# --- objects ---

G_x = 10  # stripe width
x = 2

stripes_x1 = []
stripes_x2 = []

G1_pos_x = 122
G2_pos_x = 367
G1_pos_y = 0
G2_pos_y = 0

G1_y = 60*x
G2_y = 75*x

G1_start = G1_pos_y + height - G1_y
G2_start = G2_pos_y + height - G2_y

a = 166
b = 222
for x in range(3):
    gap = a*x
    gap2 = b*x
    stripes_x1.append(pygame.Rect(G1_pos_x, (G1_start - 6*k) - gap, G_x, G1_y))
    stripes_x2.append(pygame.Rect(G2_pos_x, (G2_start - 6*k) - gap2, G_x, G2_y))

selected1 = None
selected2 = None

# --- mainloop ---

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
is_running = True

while is_running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        # --- global events ---

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            is_running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                is_running = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                for i, r in enumerate(stripes_x1):
                    if r.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        selected1 = i
                        selected_offset_y = r.y - event.pos[1]
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if selected1 is not None:  # selected can be `0` so `is not None` is required
                stripes_x1[selected1].y = event.pos[1] + selected_offset_y

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if event.button == 1:
                selected1 = None

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                for j, r in enumerate(stripes_x2):
                     if r.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        selected2 = j
                        selected_offset_y = r.y - event.pos[1]
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if selected2 is not None:  # selected can be `0` so `is not None` is required
                stripes_x2[selected2].y = event.pos[1] + selected_offset_y

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if event.button == 1:
                selected2 = None

        # --- objects events ---

        '''
       button.handle_event(event)
       '''
    # --- updates ---
        # empty
    # --- draws ---

    screen.fill(white)
    for i in range(width):
        grid_x = k * i
        grid_y = k * i

        pygame.draw.line(screen, grid_color, (grid_x, 0), (grid_x, height), 1)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, grid_color, (0, grid_y), (width, grid_y), 1)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (6 * k, height - 6 * k), (width - 6 * k, height - 6 * k), 3)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (6 * k, height - 6 * k), (6 * k, 0 * k), 3)
    # draw rect
    for r in stripes_x1:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, r)
    for s in stripes_x2:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, s)


    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please describe your goals in detail, and post the image of the traffic light coordination program that you showed me the last time (if that's still what you're trying to achieve).

Comment: What I am trying to achieve here is quite simple - time/distance graph of traffic lights coordination (green wave). Vertical green rects represent amount of green signal. Each row of green rects represent different intersection. Coordination is depicted by diagonal lines (band) between green rectangles. I must be able to edit necessary parameters like precisely move rows of green rects to adjust to best configuration, change green light length, its position according to red light, cycle, speed etc.
http://kmkrakow.pl/attachments/article/138/zielona%20fala.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move the rects simultaneously, you can put them in a list and, if one rect is selected, move them all with the help of the `rel` attribute of the MOUSEMOTION event (the relative position from the last mouse event). Here's a minimal example:

```
import sys
import pygame as pg


BLACK = pg.Color('black')
RECT_COLOR = pg.Color(78, 140, 200)


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    rect_list = [pg.Rect(100, 100+y, 20, 80) for y in range(0, 241, 120)]
    selected = False
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                for rect in rect_list:
                    if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        selected = True
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                selected = False
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
                if selected:
                    for rect in rect_list:
                        rect.y += event.rel[1]

        screen.fill(BLACK)
        for rect in rect_list:
            pg.draw.rect(screen, RECT_COLOR, rect)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: I solved my problem but I had to get rid of the lists. Your solution, though, seems much more elegant, nice. However, I can't fully grasp the code - how does this part work :
for y in range(0, 241, 120)]

Comment: `[pg.Rect(100, 100+y, 20, 80) for y in range(0, 241, 120)]` that's a [list comprehension](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/). `for y in range(0, 241, 120)` gives you the numbers 0, 120 and 240 (I just used them as the y-offsets for the rect positions).

Comment: The rel attribute of the MOUSEMOTION event is a neat method to move the rect (relative to where it's clicked) but I need to move it by a factor that is every 2 or more pixels, I can do it just by multiplying event.rel[1] but than,what's expected, it's kind of gets out of sync. Can the moving by a factor be done correctly using event.rel ?